# Teradata performance of joining tables vs joining views

Tags: sql, join, view, teradata

I have a variety of tables that I am joining together.  Each table has a primary index and most but not all are partitioned on a date field.  Each table has an associated view.

If I write a query in the form

```
select
*
from view1
join view2
on pi1 = pi2
join view3
on pi1 = pi3
join view4
on pi1 = pi4
```

...

I run into a out of spool space problem.  Would it be better to query the tables directly?  Would it be better to create some intermediate tables and do a few joins at a time, then create new indices and partitions on the intermediate tables?

Comment: Your code sample suggests a Cartesian Product because you are not joining on any fields.  Does this represent your actual attempt?

Comment: Sorry, being careless today.  I am joining on the indices, in some applications I will also filter using the partition date

Comment: You say that each table has an associated view.  Is there a difference between the table and the view?  If not, what purpose does the view serve?

Comment: The view is more or less a select * for the table, not sure why it exists

Comment: The view likely has an access locking modifier on it to allow for dirty reads of the data. Not an uncommon practice in Teradata.

Comment: How large are the tables? What is the data distribution? What is your spool allocation? Keep in mind, Spool is a shared resource across all sessions for a given user. Do you know what step of the query plan it is spooling out on?

Comment: I think it will be better if you can update the question with EXPLAIN plan of the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating intermediate tables should not be neccessary.

Without knowing further details there might be a simple cause:

- There a two tables like **invoice** and **invoice**_line, the logical
  PK is (invoice_number) and (invoice_number, line_number).
- The Primary INdex of both tables is (invoice_number) to get all rows
  for an invoice on a single AMP for faster processing.
- Both tables are partitioned by invoice_date (in fact keeping the
  invoice_date in the invoice_line is not needed, because it's the same
  date for each line. It's done to get matching partitioning on both
  tables)
- The join doesn't inlcude the invoice_date, it's just based on
  invoice_number. This is correct based on the PK-FK but will result in a
  very slow join because the optimizer doesn't know which
  invoice_number is stored in which partition -> all partitions need to
  be accessed.

In a case like that you **must** use invoice_date as an additional join condition.

Otherwise you must supply more info:

As already mentioned: you should post the Explain.

Additionally it might help to get the PI definition (plus partitioning) and some statistics information. 
The easiest way to get the DDL of all objects is a **SHOW** in front of the select (unless you DBA restricted that), stats are returned by **HELP STATS tablename;**

Comment: Thanks!  Adding the date field which is used for the partitions made things much faster, even though the join is really based on the primary key - foreign key

Answer (score 2):

You should first check the "Explain" output of your query. [if you are using Teradata SQL Assistant, then just select your query and press F6 - this will output the Parsing Engine's(PE) plan about how to execute your query].

I suspect that you will see a lot of "re-distribution" [I think, Teradata is a closet Socialist] in the Explain output - remember for two rows to be joined, they must be located on the same AMP. If they are not, by virtue of different PI on each of the tables you are joining via views, redistribution will be necessary.

You would also want to check if you need to collect any statistics on some of columns. Improper statistics could lead to the PE coming up with rediculous query plans. For ex: If one of the table you are joining is huge but a skewed table - the PE might incorrectly detect that it is actually a small table and try to duplicate it to all the AMPS (instead of re-distribution) and this usually results in you running out of space.

Why don't you go ahead and post the "Explain" of your query?
Set this option first: DIAGNOSTIC HELPSTATS ON FOR SESSION;

Without looking at what the views are doing it is difficult to tell.